# Storing the value of time in variable and updating it

Tags: c, variables

I am using WinCE7.I need to store the value of time whenever a particular input is high in variable like `t1`. Then if the input is again high, store the value of time in another variable like `t2`. How to do this in c.

Right now I am saving time in t1 like below:

```
sprintf(time," %d:%d:%d:%d\n",systemTime.wHour,systemTime.wMinute,systemTime.wSecond,systemTime.wMilliseconds);

if(input==high)
{
 strcpy(t1,time);
 printf("time %s\n",t1);
}
```

Comment: By storing the struct such as with `SYSTEMTIME t1, t2; t1 = systemTime; /*...*/ t2 = systemTime;`

Comment: Elaborate a bit more about that variable. If it is modifiable once it go high?

Comment: Variable can not be modify. If the input is high second time, value of time needs to be saved in another variable.

Comment: Does your variable is connected to any interrupt etc.? which automatically goes up and down?

Comment: It is connected to a sensor. When sensor is high. It gives high signal to input so input is also high.

Comment: @Mazhar I have made a logic for it. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays for storing multiple times etc. below is a kind of pseudo code. change according to your actual code.

```
char t1[30][20], time[20];
int counter = 0 , low=0;
    while(counter < 30) {
        sprintf(time," %d:%d:%d:%d\n",systemTime.wHour,systemTime.wMinute,systemTime.wSecond,systemTime.wMilliseconds);

        if(input==high)
        {
         strcpy(t1[counter],time);
         printf("time %s\n",t1[counter]);
        //reset the input or whatever
         input = low;
         counter++; // change index 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an integer value `i = 0` to count the number of times the input is high. For example:

```
i = 0;
if(input==high)
{
 i++;
 if(i==1)  //Input is high for the first time
 { 
   strcpy(t1,time);
   printf("time %s\n",t1);
 }
 if(i==2)  //Input is high for the second time
 { 
   strcpy(t2,time);
   printf("time %s\n",t2);
 }
 if(i==3)  //Input is high for the third time
 { 
   strcpy(t3,time);
   printf("time %s\n",t3);
 }

 //same for other 
}
```

Comment: Good! you tried yourself (Y). But this way increase number of instructions. Try to use loop to decrease instructions. Look closely at logic made by you is same as mine with exception of loop.

Comment: Oh yeah.Thanks. I'll convert it in loops.